# The context api in reactjs does not provide me the value. It just returning the initial value or state

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Here how I create a context api ->

I wrap the entire app in `main.jsx` file, then create the context api and provide value in `Testcontext.jsx` file and then I call it from `Signup.jsx` file. When I call the context api I don't get the value. I did this same thing in my other project and there it works but here it doesn't.

Here is my code:

`main.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools'
import { BrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import router from "./Routes/Routes";
import AuthAndRoleContext from "./Context/FirebaseAndRoleContext";
import Testcontext from "./Context/Testcontext";

const queryClient = new QueryClient()
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider  router={router} >
         
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <React.StrictMode>
              <Testcontext>
                <App />
              </Testcontext>
            <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
          </React.StrictMode>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      
  </RouterProvider>
);
```

`Testcontext.jsx`

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';


export const TestContextProvider = createContext(null);

const Testcontext = ({children}) => {
    const data = {x:"user 1",y:"user 2"}

    return (
        <TestContextProvider.Provider value={data}>
            {children}
        </TestContextProvider.Provider>
    );
};

export default Testcontext;
```

`Signup.jsx`

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { UserAndRoleContext } from "../../Context/FirebaseAndRoleContext";
import { TestContextProvider } from "../../Context/Testcontext";

const Signup = () => {

  const {x} = useContext(TestContextProvider)
  console.log(x)



  return (
    <div>
      <p>my component</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

Here I'm getting this error if I use, createContext().

> Cannot destructure property 'x' of 'useContext(...)' as it is undefined.

And here is my project tree

src-> Context-> Testcontext.jsx,
src-> Pages-> Signup-> Signup.jsx

I want the data x:"user 1" in my `Signup.jsx` file from `Testcontext.jsx` file.

Comment: I was unable to replicate the issue. The above code works fine for me.

Comment: I used vite and there it does not work no idea why and I didn't find anything internet and also it works when I use the creat-react-app